# How do I access the data in Google Cloud Function written in Python passed via JS FormData from frontend?

Tags: python, reactjs, python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, form-data

I have a ReactJS Frontend, where I am sending a data along with POST request's body payload in the `FormData` structure, but I am unable to access the data in my Google Cloud Function written Python using `request` parameter`. Below is my frontend code:

```
handleUpload = async (file: any, dataFromChild: any) => {
      const token = await auth?.currentUser?.getIdToken();

      if (!token) {
        enqueueSnackbar(`Session Expired. Login again`, { variant: "error" });
        window.location.href("/login")
      }

      if (file) {
        try {
          const snackbarRef = enqueueSnackbar("Uploading File...", {
            variant: "info",
          });
          const payload = new FormData();
          payload.append("file", file[0]);
          payload.append("name", dataFromChild?.fileName);
          payload.append("description", dataFromChild?.fileDesc);
          payload.append("title", dataFromChild?.selectedType);
          payload.append("price", 0);

          const response = await fetch(
            `[Cloud Function URL]`,
            {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
              },
              body: payload
            }
          );
          closeSnackbar(snackbarRef);
          if (response.ok) {
            enqueueSnackbar(`File uploaded successfully.`, {
              variant: "success",
            });
            this.setState({ fileUploaded: false });

          } else {
            enqueueSnackbar(`Error uploading file.`, { variant: "error" });
            this.setState({ fileUploaded: false });

          }
        } catch (error) {
          enqueueSnackbar(`Error occurred while uploading the file.`, {
            variant: "error",
          });
          this.setState({ fileUploaded: false });

        }
      }
    };
```

I tried to access the data using following way in Python:

```
import functions_framework

@functions_framework.http
def main(request):
    headers = set_cors_headers(request)

    if request.method == "OPTIONS":
        return headers

    get_data(request)


def get_data(request):
    print(request.files['file'])
    print(request.form['name']
    .
    .
```

But it did not get any data. I even tried to get data this way:

```
def get_data(request):
    print(request.files.get('file')
    print(request.form.get('name')
    .
    .
```

But all in vain. Anyone tell me what wrong am I doing?

Comment: You're not showing how you're actually POSTing the data.

Comment: Actually, I am the backend guy and the code is written by the Frontend guy. Let me update the question with full frontend code.

Comment: You're also not telling us which Python web framework you're working with. I'll guess Flask from `files` and `form`.

Comment: @AKX I have updated the ReactJS code and also updated some description for you to see (actually, the Python code is written in Google Cloud Function), and I am using `@functions_framework` of GCP. Please check the updated question.

Comment: @AKX I have also updated Python code to include the GCP's `functions_framework` please check now.

Comment: The frontend shouldn't need to set the content-type header; it's automatically set for FormData. Anyway, you have you tried `print(request.headers, request.form, request.files)` or similar, so you can see whether you're getting _any_ data?

Comment: I tried `request.form` and `request.files`. I did not try `request.headers`. Am I supposed to get the data via headers of the request?

Comment: `request.form` and `request.files` returns empty results.

Comment: @AKX any help? I mean what wrong am I doing that I am not getting any data?

Comment: You should be seeing at least a content-length and a content-type if the data is heading anywhere near your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reason, but in my case, I had to remove the line of code from my frontend, where it is setting `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data` before sending the `POST` request. So my updated frontend code looks like:

```
handleUpload = async (file: any, dataFromChild: any) => {
      const token = await auth?.currentUser?.getIdToken();

      if (!token) {
        enqueueSnackbar(`Session Expired. Login again`, { variant: "error" });
        window.location.href("/login")
      }

      if (file) {
        try {
          const snackbarRef = enqueueSnackbar("Uploading File...", {
            variant: "info",
          });
          const payload = new FormData();
          payload.append("file", file[0]);
          payload.append("name", dataFromChild?.fileName);
          payload.append("description", dataFromChild?.fileDesc);
          payload.append("title", dataFromChild?.selectedType);
          payload.append("price", 0);

          const response = await fetch(
            `[Cloud Function URL]`,
            {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data", // REMOVED THIS LINE
              },
              body: payload
            }
          );
          closeSnackbar(snackbarRef);
          if (response.ok) {
            enqueueSnackbar(`File uploaded successfully.`, {
              variant: "success",
            });
            this.setState({ fileUploaded: false });

          } else {
            enqueueSnackbar(`Error uploading file.`, { variant: "error" });
            this.setState({ fileUploaded: false });

          }
        } catch (error) {
          enqueueSnackbar(`Error occurred while uploading the file.`, {
            variant: "error",
          });
          this.setState({ fileUploaded: false });

        }
      }
    };
```